# Multiple includes of modules containing the same class

Tags: php

So I need to include modular code/libraries in my project, a new library:

**Library A**:

```
a.php: class A;
```

**Library B**: (with v1.0 checked out from A)

```
b.php: include_once a.php; class B extends A;
```

**Library C**: (with v2.0 checked out from A)

```
c.php: include_once a.php; class C extends A;
```

**Library D**:

```
d.php: include_once b.php,c.php;
```

This obviously leads to name conflict (`cannot redeclare A`).

I cannot touch either of the libraries as they are frequently pulled from elsewhere. Also, I need the result to be another library, so nested namespaces is not an option. But I guess there must be plenty of other projects with the same problem?? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: my guess would be to use `include_once()` rather than `include()`. Find more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Comment: This doesn't prevent the name conflict. Both B and C make use of A.

Comment: Well, without any good suggestions so far I guess I have to go for this: Use the same library version everywhere, and include only if `!class_exists()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [require_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or [include_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), in place of your `include`s.

These may affect performance, as memory and processing has to be used to keep track of included classes and check against it, but it's the easiest solution. How much they do, depends on how many include/require_once are in your single page load.

More complicated ones would implement a class autoloader, but you might not want to go there...

EDIT--

If I understand well your problem, it's a dependency problem. Libraries B and C both refer to A, but each refers to a different version of A. If that's the case, the solution is not trivial: any use of require_once or include_once will lead to undetermined first loaded version of A to be used. Any use of include will result in class duplication. I don't think you can solve the issue by just using these functions. What you'd need to do would be to manage library dependencies.

For example, an autoloader that recognises several versions of a class library and loads the most recent one (this assuming that you keep backwards compatibility across versions). You could also try to use nested classes, to keep each library's dependencies isolated and self-contained.

Comment: Actually I do use require_once, but this works with regard to a specific file, not a class. a.php included in b.php is included only once. The other a.php included in c.php is included only once. The name conflict, however, persists.

Comment: The idea regarding nested classes is interesting, but then I cannot use inheritance, which in fact is a show-stopper.

Comment: Then I guess the only option left is an intelligent autoloader. You may approach this problem by defining a common list of folders where the autoloader may search for classes, and implement priority by detecting the most recent version (or use another criteria if appropriate) of the library to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a class got declared already, in case your filenames are different for each version.
Example:

```
if (!class_exists('A')) {
    include a-XX.php;
}
```

Note that this way you only load one version of your class.

Comment: Problem is that there are two versions of A, taken care of the CVS. I need to load both, as they are needed in B and C.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well

your problem is that

Library B And C includes the same file which is A

And you want B And C In D in the other  B and C which has the same file 
which is A so it shows

> **Fatal error**: Cannot redeclare class A in

ok --->
in files ***c.php*** , ***b.php*** And ***d.php*** `include_once 'a.php'`; **OR** 
`require_once 'a.php'`;

Comment: Actually I do use require_once, but this works with regard to a specific file, not a class. a.php included in b.php is included only once. The other a.php included in c.php is included only once. The name conflict persists.

Comment: if you required any of c,or,b in another incloded file like `z` as an ex. you must include it just z only to avoid recalling the file